# htaccess rewrite causes 500 error instead of 404

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I've recently added this little bit of code to my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Ok, I understand what's happening here, I think.  This little bit of code to remove PHP file extensions causes a loop if the document is not found.  This loop causes a 500 server error instead of the (proper) 404.  Unfortunately I have very little understanding of what these rewrites are actually doing, so I don't know how to rewrite it to only trigger this redirect if the document exists.

I've done some reading and I'm not sure what Apache considers a "regular" file. I mean it works, but why wouldn't the first line be `-f` instead of `!-f`?  Is `-u` the only way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should test if new path points to an existing file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Otherwise you will get an infinite recursion (error 500).

Comment: +1000 internets to you sir, been looking for the answer to this for an hour.

Answer (score 2):

The intention of these rules is, as you suggested, to allow someone to request a page without including the PHP extension. So if you had a file on **example.com** called **about.php** then someone would be able to use the URL **http://example.com/about** in order to access it.

However if someone requests **http://example.com/about.php** directly you don't want it to be rewritten as **http://example.com/about.php.php**. Similarly, you don't want requests for images, CSS stylesheets etc to be rewritten. This is where the 2 RewriteConds come in, they are conditions saying that the rewriting should only take place if the request doesn't match a file (`!-f`) or directory (`!-d`) that actually exists on the site.

To answer why you're getting a 500, this could be because the permissions in Apache are configured not to allow rewrite rules in an htaccess file or one of several other reasons. Check the end of your error_log to see if there are any messages in there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the -f switch, I understand that now.  But I would think it would attempt to forward to 404.php and then there'd be a 404 error, not jump into any loops.  I'm not seeing anything in our error log related to this, which seems... wrong.  Shouldn't a server error always put something in the log?

Comment: What is your ErrorDocument (specifying the 404 page) currently set to?

Answer (score 0):

First off, here is some reference to better understand the mod_rewrite module:

[mod_rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

[mod_rewrite Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/)

The problem you are seeing is that it is checking for both conditions, the default is [AND], when you only want to check for one, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think the 2 RewriteConds are correct as an AND condition. i.e. the request does not correspond to an actual file AND the request does not correspond to an actual directory.

Comment: Right, otherwise it's always true (an object can't be a file AND a directory), therefore if you test "(NOT a file) OR (NOT a directory)" you get "TRUE OR FALSE" for directories and "FALSE OR TRUE" for files, both of which evaluate to TRUE.

I know this is an old post, but figured I'd provide a little explanation for anyone else who happens upon it while trying to work with their rewrites :)